# How to perform arithmetic operations on dataframe columns using text in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: "Temperature", "Pressure" and "Precipitation". I wish to add a new column to the dataframe, which is called "Ratio", which is the ratio of the "Temperature" and "Precipitation" columns. However, I need to do this using text, exactly as follows:
The text string to be used is "x1/x3". How do I make x1 and x3 refer to "Temperature" and "Precipitation" (and x2 to "Pressure"), and evaluate the new column in R? I found the parse() function being used for evaluating numerical expressions, so can that be used here?

Comment: we can index the columns by names or indexes. Do you want to conver the string to an expression or maybe to indices?

Comment: Is this a homework question? homework is ok, but share more context, and show some effort

Comment: @GuedesBF This is not a homework question, it is a part of a larger program that I was  writing, Thank you for your sample helper code.

Answer (score 0):

We may have to do the operation on a renamed data.frame.
`rename_with` to create the `x1:x3` names.
Then we can `eval`uate the expression created with `parse` inside `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
    mutate(ratio = 
               df |>
               rename_with(\(x) paste0('x', seq)) |> 
               mutate( ratio = eval(parse(text = "x1/x3"))) |> 
               pull(ratio))

  Temperature Pressure Precipitation ratio
1          29       20             8 3.625
2          30       24            10 3.000
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Temperature = 29:30, Pressure = c(20, 24), Precipitation = c(8, 10))

 Temperature Pressure Precipitation
1          29       20             8
2          30       24            10
```

the renaming is a bit more generalizable to other data.frames if we use `paste0('x', seq_along(pick(everything()))))` instead of `paste0('x', 1:3)`

Answer (score 0):

The R `parse` function will convert a character object to an unevaluated expression. Then when the expression is used as the first argument to `eval`, the infix operator `"/"` can be evaluated inside a dataframe specified as the environment.

```
df <- data.frame(Temperature = 29:30, Pressure = c(20, 24), Precipitation = c(8, 10))
expr <- "x1/x2"  #just a length-1 character object
df2 <- setNames(df, paste0("x", 1:length(df)))
df2
#------------------
  x1 x2 x3
1 29 20  8
2 30 24 10
eval( parse(text=expr), env=df2)
# [1] 1.45 1.25
 df2$ratio <- eval( parse(text=expr), env=df2)
 df2
#------
  x1 x2 x3 ratio
1 29 20  8  1.45
2 30 24 10  1.25
```

Comment: Thank you @IRTFM for the answer. This should work.